# Multicolor polyline on UI thread

Tags: android, google-maps

my code snippet is something like this .

```
 int size = listPoints.size();
        PolylineOptions optline = new PolylineOptions();
        PolylineOptions optline2 = new PolylineOptions();
        optline.geodesic(true);
        optline.width(10);
        optline2.geodesic(true);
        optline2.width(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {

            TRKPT pointD = listPoints.get(i);
            TRKPT pointA = listPoints.get(i + 1);
            int green = (int) ((float) 255 - (float) (i / (float) size) * (float) 255);
            int red = (int) ((float) 0 + (float) (i / (float) size) * (float) 255);

            optline.add(new LatLng(pointD.getLat(), pointD.getLon()), new LatLng(pointA.getLat(), pointA.getLon()));
            optline2.add(new LatLng(pointD.getLat(), pointD.getLon()), new LatLng(pointA.getLat(), pointA.getLon()));

            if(i%2 == 0){
                optline.color(Color.rgb(red, green, 0));
                mMap.addPolyline(optline);
                optline = new PolylineOptions();
                optline.geodesic(true);
                optline.width(10);
            }
            else{
                optline2.color(Color.rgb(red, green, 0));
                mMap.addPolyline(optline2);
                optline2 = new PolylineOptions();
                optline2.geodesic(true);
                optline2.width(10);
            }
        }
```

> this logic works fine for say 100 -400 points when points are more like 1000 or so it blocks the UI thread. and i can not draw these polyline on background as drawing polyline is operation on view so how can i optimise colored polyline plotting. i would really appreciate your help guys, please help me out here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Thread where you do all the drawing parts on a Bitmap/Canvas in memory, then the UiThread should only display that Bitmap.
Obliviously that Bitmap should be used only from one thread in the same time, so you have to use some Synchronization procedure to write and read in different times avoiding to do them in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only two colors for polyline you can reduce number of polylines: use dashed [Stroke pattern](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes#stroke_pattern) and draw not many polylines with different color for each polyline, but only two polylines: first - solid with one color, and second (on the same points) - dashed with other color over the first.

If you don't need all of your source points, you can reduce number of polyline points (without polyline shape lose): simplify polyline with [`PolyUtil.simplify()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#simplify-java.util.List-double-) method and draw both polylines (or each segment) not on source but on simplified points set.

Comment: i can not use PolyUtils.simplify() as i need all LatLng to perform some operation . i thing in for loop i am creating too may object thats the issue.

Comment: @akshay_shahane But you can use `PolyUtils.simplify()` polyline only for visualization and use other not added to map "full of points" polyline for process your task.